# Javascript: How to make sure window.open returns same window, if already opened

Tags: javascript

I am working on a web based application, in which I have to open popup window. I am using `window.open()` method to open the popup, like this:

```
window.open(url, "popupWin");
```

where url contains the URL I would like my popup window to navigate to. Now, the problem is, if I execute `window.open()` from multiple tabs (with same or different URLs), at least on Chrome, it might / might not give you the same window which was opened earlier. This behaviour is inconsistent, I mean, either it should get me fresh window every time, or it should get me previously opened window every time.

I need to persist the same popup window for entire domain. How can I do that?

Comment: You can't. A popup can only be accessed from the tab that opened it.

Comment: Are you sure? I would think it could be accessed from the same origin. I would guess the inconsistency depends on the content of the window. If the content is same origin as the script that opens it and the same origin as the NEXT script that tries to access it, it should remain. If not, a new window would be opened. Check the console for access denied

Comment: how could it be accessed from the same origin if the popup window object reference won't appear on another tab?

Comment: Hi @mplungjan, thanks for the reply. Actually, I exported code to open window in a separate JS file, containing a module like function. So, it is the same code which is getting executed on different tabs. But, sometimes, I guess when you open a new URL (like google.com) in a new tab, and then you open your own URL in another new tab, it breaks the pattern on chrome and you will get a new window opened.

Answer (score 2):

Well looks like there is a direction to go or at least to give it a try.

It fully remains on `localStorage` which gives you ability to share the knowledge across your tabs within a single domain.

The code I give below *does not work yet* (it is only a direction), so don't expect too much from running it as it is.

What it does: it saves the popups by the url in a `localStorage` and when you try to open a new one with the same url it won't do that. If you don't want to distinguish them by URL it is even simpler: store boolean in a localStorage instead of an object.

What it does not do but should:

1. it should listen to the popup `onunload` (close) event and reset the `localStorage` information accordingly. Best for you here is just to set your `localStorage` `boolean` value to `false`
2. it should listen to the current tab `onunload` (reload, close) event and also reset something according to Your logic. As I understand the best for you would be just check whether this tab is the last one from your domain (you can also do this using localStorage, e.g. on every new tab adding its identifier, e.g. creation timestamp and destroying it on tab close) and if it is set your `localStorage` `boolean` value to `false`.

This, I think, would be enough to solve the problem. And finally a small piece of code:

```
// get the localstorage url map
function getOpenPopups() {
  var obj = localStorage.getItem('mypopups');

  return obj ? JSON.parse(obj) : {};
}

// set the localstorage url map
function setOpenPopups(object) {
  localStorage.setItem('mypopups', JSON.stringify(object))
}

// open the popup
function popup(url, title) {
  var popups = getOpenPopups();

  // check whether popup with this url is already open
  // if not then set it and open the popup
  if (!popups[url]) {
    popups[url] = true;

        setOpenPopups(popups);

    return window.open('abc', 'cde');
  }
  else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yyos8rk4/1/)

Comment: Hi @smnbbrv, thanks for answer. Actually, what I would really like to do is have a reference to the popup window whenever I call `popup` function, something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/PrakharMishra/gp5k3evx/1/.

Comment: @PrakharMishra I'm afraid the proposed way is the only way you can do. You won't get a reference to the popup just because it belongs to another tab / window/ thread. You also can't store a reference in your localStorage. Still you can communicate to the popup from any tab: just push the notifications in a localStorage and read them in timeout loop / interval on another side. I know, this is not the easiest way, but I am not sure you can choose anything else

Answer (score 0):

From [w3c documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) we can see that `window.open()` returns a reference to the newly created window, or null if the call failed. That means we can keep it in memory and check for `closed` flag of that window.

```
var newWindow = window.open('/some/path', 'TestWindow');
// ...
if (!newWindow.closed) {

}
```

Keep in mind that if window with following name exists, page will be loaded in the same window without opening new one.
Other variants of `name` parameter like _blank, _self, _top, _parent you can find in official docs too.

Comment: Hello @oleg-meleshko, is there any way to share it with multiple / different tabs? Or, to make it survive redirects?

Comment: You can get current window name by using `window.name` in any opened window. Having that you could use some single server/client side storage to keep an information about specific window status.